# How to solve a memory leak in Nuxt Js when detached elements keeps adding up?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, memory-leaks, nuxt.js

I am facing a memory leak issue in my nuxtjs project. I have tried to identify what's causing this issue [image: Heap profiling of the app] and cannot solve this .

What I was able to understand that it has something to do with the i18n library as I can see i18n in all the detached text . I even tried to remove all the Plugins and components from global plugin library that required me to use it using Vue.use() .

Some of the detached elements are Headings and Paragraph Inside the Marques which consist of dynamic children using v-for (I've added :key in the children).

I am using the following as per my package.json  :

```
    {
  "name": "website_sourcecode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "build-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nuxt build",
    "prod-debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/nuxt",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "analyze": "nuxt build --analyze"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/nuxt": "^0.7.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/emotion": "0.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^7.3.1",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "ap-style-title-case": "^1.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cssjson": "^2.1.3",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.7.0",
    "html-minifier": "^4.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-jsonld": "^1.5.7",
    "nuxt-matomo": "^1.2.4",
    "nuxt-purgecss": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-flux": "5.1.9",
    "vue-good-table": "^2.21.11",
    "vue-lazyload": "^3.0.0-rc.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-text-marquee": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/image": "^0.6.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

**Please help me as I am so stuck in this and need your help**

Thanks in Advance